# Can a JAXB-annotated class known the JAXBContext or JAXBIntrospector instance?

Tags: java, reflection, binding, jaxb, introspection

Can a JAXB-annotated class known the JAXBContext or JAXBIntrospector instance which is used to marshal/unmarshal the class?

Something like:

```
@XmlType
class Hello {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name = "";

    // called by JAXB
    public Hello(){
        JAXBIntrospector i = [some-magic-utility-class].getCurrentIntrospector();
    }

}
```

More specific: I need the class instance to know (when being marshalled/unmarshalled) [which other classes are known](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.html#isElement%28java.lang.Object%29) to the current JAXBContext.

Comment: I'm curious why you would need to know that...

Comment: @MatrixFrog I need this to let a JAXB-annotated object decide, which other objects should be converted for JAXB-usage and which are already known to JAXBContext and need no wrapping. More specific, it's needed for a universal wrapper, similar to JAXBElement.